# Database Connection golang mysql

Tags: mysql, go, switch-statement, variable-declaration

I am trying to write a test program for my Go code. This code has a global `db` variable which I initialize in the `main` package.

```
package database

import(
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

//Data type that defines one identity
type element struct {
     title string
     date string
     url string
     remoteUrl string
}


//global database object for every package
var (
   db *sql.DB
)

// params  elem : element to be inserted ,     folder     : folderName 
func insertNoticeData( elem element, folder string) bool  {

     switch folder {
         case "Results" : stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT results_ipu SET title=?, date=?, url=?, remoteUrl=?")
         case "Notices" : stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT notice_ipu SET title=?, date=?, url=?, remoteUrl=?")
         case "Datesheets" : stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT datesheet_ipu SET title=?, date=?, url=?, remoteUrl=?")
     }

     res, err1 := stmt.Exec(elem.title, elem.date, elem.url, elem.remoteUrl)
     if err1 != nil {
     fmt.Println("Error inserting in database ")
     return false
     }
     return true
}
```

It's giving me an error: `undefined symbol stmt`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables declared in the `case` branches of a [`switch`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) statement are *scoped* to the case branch, they are not accessible (not in scope) outside of the `case`.

Solution is simple, declare `stmt` and the `err` variables before the `switch`, and use [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) (`=`) instead of the [short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) (`:=`):

```
var stmt *sql.Stmt
var err error

switch folder {
case "Results":
    stmt, err = db.Prepare("INSERT results_ipu SET title=?, date=?, url=?, remoteUrl=?")
case "Notices":
    stmt, err = db.Prepare("INSERT notice_ipu SET title=?, date=?, url=?, remoteUrl=?")
case "Datesheets":
    stmt, err = db.Prepare("INSERT datesheet_ipu SET title=?, date=?, url=?, remoteUrl=?")
}

if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

res, err1 := stmt.Exec(elem.title, elem.date, elem.url, elem.remoteUrl)
```

Source from the spec:

[Declarations and Scope:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

> Go is lexically scoped using [blocks](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks):
> ...
>
> 5. The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.
>
> ...

And [Spec: Blocks:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks)

> A block is a possibly empty sequence of declarations and statements within matching brace brackets.
>
> [...] In addition to explicit blocks in the source code, there are implicit blocks:
>
> 5. Each clause in a ["switch"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) or ["select"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) statement acts as an implicit block.

Comment: thanks mate
just started with golang few days ago so still a newbie :P